# Keep specific function signatures in a generic type constraint - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints

At first: sorry for the long post and that in fact I have two different questions here. But since both are so closely related to each other (two different approaches to reach the same goals) I thought it's better to keep them in one post.

I am trying to implement a lightweight TypeScript signalling / event framework, where

- all possible signal names are known and have IntelliSense support
- their signatures (arguments and return value) are strongly typed and have IntelliSense support as well

I know there exist some solutions which achieve similar goals somehow, but I have a specific
simple to use design in mind which makes use of the newer TypeScript generic index type constraint features - but for now I am obviously not capable to master them on my own :)

I am using TypeScript 4.2.3.

I tried two different approaches with different non-working outcomes...

**First approach**

This compiles but we don't have any types on the signal arguments and return values:

```js
// Define signals by name and a function, which specifies SignalArgs
// and SignalValue (return value).
type Signals = {
  hello: (name: string) => string;
  add: (val1: number, val2: number) => number;
};

// Generic class which should implement on() and emit() with arguments
// bound to the specific signals enumerated in the Signals type.
class SignalBus<Signals> {
  on<Key extends string & keyof Signals, Spec extends (...args: any) => any & Signals[Key]>(
    signal: Key,
    handler: (
      signal: Signal<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>>,
      ...args: Parameters<Spec>
    ) => Promise<ReturnType<Spec>>,
  ): SignalConnection<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>> {
    // ...
    console.log("on", signal, handler);
    const connection = (handler as unknown) as SignalConnection<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>>;
    connection.signal = signal;
    return connection;
  }

  async emit<Key extends string & keyof Signals, Spec extends (...args: any) => any & Signals[Key]>(
    signal: Key,
    ...args: Parameters<Spec>
  ): Promise<Signal<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>>> {
    // ...
    console.log("emit", signal, args);
    return new Signal<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>>(signal, args);
  }
}

// Signal objects represent a signal at runtime
class Signal<SignalArgs extends unknown[] = [], SignalValue = any> {
  public value: SignalValue;
  constructor(public signal: string, public args: SignalArgs) {}
}

// SignalConnection objects enclose the handler callback, signal name and probably more
type SignalConnection<SignalArgs extends unknown[], SignalResult> = {
  (signal: Signal<SignalArgs, SignalResult>, ...args: SignalArgs): Promise<SignalResult | void>;
  signal: string;
};

// Create a SignalBus specific to the Signals defined above
const bus = new SignalBus<Signals>();

// Fine
bus.on("hello", async (_signal, name) => `Hello ${name}`);

// Should give type error, because two numeric arguments and numeric return value are expected
bus.on("add", async (_signal, name: string) => `Shouldn't be accepted ${name}`);

// Should give type error, because only one string argument is expected
bus.emit("hello", "World", "shouldn't be accepted");
```

The problem is that the specific function signature, e.g. in the on() Method, gets lost:

```js
on<Key extends string & keyof Signals, Spec extends (...args: any) => any & Signals[Key]>(...)
```

This happens with the use of `Spec extends (...args: any) => any`.

I understand that I have to constraint the `Signals[Key]` property to be a callable
function to make the `Parameters<>` and `ReturnValue<>` utility types work.

But how can I do that without loosing the type information of the `Signals[Key]` functions?

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

**Another approach, another problem ;)**

Here I definine a generic `signal<>` type which consists of the signal parameter and return value types and accessing them via index - but with no luck as well...

When using the SignalBus class the compiler complains about non assignable `never` types. See the comments at the bottom of the code example:

```js
// Generic type to specify signal arguments and return value.
type signal<SignalArgs extends unknown[] = [], SignalResult = void> = {
  args: SignalArgs;
  result: SignalResult;
};

// Define signals by name and the generic signal<> type.
type Signals = {
  hello: signal<[name: string], string>;
  add: signal<[val: number, val2: number], string>;
};

// Generic class which should implement on() and emit() with arguments
// bound to the specific signals enumerated in the Signals type.
class SignalBus<Signals> {
  on<Key extends string & keyof Signals, Spec extends signal & Signals[Key]>(
    signal: Key,
    handler: (
      signal: Signal<Spec["args"], Spec["result"]>,
      ...args: Spec["args"]
    ) => Promise<Spec["result"]>,
  ): SignalConnection<Spec["args"], Spec["result"]> {
    // ...
  }

  async emit<Key extends string & keyof Signals, Spec extends signal & Signals[Key]>(
    signal: Key,
    ...args: Spec["args"]
  ): Promise<Signal<Spec["args"], Spec["result"]>> {
    // ...
  }
}

// Signal objects represent a signal at runtime
class Signal<SignalArgs extends unknown[] = [], SignalValue = any> {
  public value: SignalValue;
  constructor(public signal: string, public args: SignalArgs) {}
}

// SignalConnection objects enclose the handler callback, signal name and probably more
type SignalConnection<SignalArgs extends unknown[], SignalResult> = {
  (signal: Signal<SignalArgs, SignalResult>, ...args: SignalArgs): Promise<SignalResult | void>;
  signal: string;
};

// Create a SignalBus specific to the Signals defined above
const bus = new SignalBus<Signals>();

// Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<never>'.
//   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. ts(2322)
bus.on("hello", async (_signal, name) => `Hello ${name}`);

// Argument of type '(_signal: Signal<never, never>, name: string) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(signal: Signal<never, never>, ...args: never) =>
// Promise<never>'.
//   Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<never>'. ts(2345)
bus.on("add", async (_signal, name: string) => `Shouldn't be accepted ${name}`);

// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. ts(2345)
bus.emit("hello", "World", "shouldn't be accepted");
```

It looks the type constraint `Spec extends signal & Signals[Key]` does never
match. Why?

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Can you add the typedefinitions for Signal and SignalConnection?

Comment: I just did, so the examples are now free of any dependencies. The first one now compiles standalone and runs and gives some log output.

Comment: Is an answer for your first approach enough? I'm not quite sure if you just tried it because the first was not working. If not it's probably better to actually split them into two questions

Comment: Absolutely ;). It is my favorite anyway because I find that writing a function declaration is simpler and more expressive than writing tupel types. I think it's required to defer the concrete function signatures but I can't get it working because defer is allowed only in conditional type constraints and I am continuously failing to apply them here... Thanks in advance for looking into this!

Comment: Of course I meant "infer" instead of "defer". Unfortunately I wasn't in the 5 minute timeout for editing my comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

The approach is not working because of the following extends clause in one of the generics:

```
Spec extends (...args: any) => any & Signals[Key]
```

Since `Signals` in the example should always be a collection of key/function-pairs, it will eventually be evaluated into something like this:

```
Spec extends (...args: any) => any & ((exampleArg: string) => string)
```

The intersection of `(...args: any) => any & ((exampleArg: string) => string)` will always be `(...args: any) => any`. This stays true for any other possible function. What is needed is the restriction of `Signals` always to be a collection of key/function-pairs. Thus the necessary change to make this example work is the following:

```
// add restriction to Signals
class SignalBus<Signals extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => ()>> {
                               // remove (...args: any[]) => any &
  on<Key extends string & keyof Signals, Spec extends Signals[Key]>(
    signal: Key,
    handler: (
      signal: Signal<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>>,
      ...args: Parameters<Spec>
    ) => Promise<ReturnType<Spec>>,
  ): SignalConnection<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>> {
    // ...
    console.log("on", signal, handler);
    const connection = (handler as unknown) as SignalConnection<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>>;
    connection.signal = signal;
    return connection;
  }
                                         // remove (...args: any) => any &
  async emit<Key extends string & keyof Signals, Spec extends Signals[Key]>(
    signal: Key,
    ...args: Parameters<Spec>
  ): Promise<Signal<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>>> {
    // ...
    console.log("emit", signal, args);
    return new Signal<Parameters<Spec>, ReturnType<Spec>>(signal, args);
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDtKgM6wObwIYBtmgEYCeoWAtkpvACaiajQCu8AxgC6wD28ANKAO4ALWMwEoADpGaw4kPAGV0WbAEEATmmQAoELWqgFGHADUcDJAApVkVg1XxQAN1OQAlADpNrQhP2KceAF5QAG9NUFABSGxsDgAuUHMySHjkVlUENBdQAIA+FDSMgG4w2ioqePMnbABGePgGUnxIVV4qgCY6hqbVLNySLubigF9i7TAAcUhEdOZQZmxMZDxBYVFkAQ4GbBpYUjFsSHJ4VlAucyzKGkPYVnP+G9FMdQap1i0dfE29Vg5QVkjxJJpMIUH5cKApi9VJhWJAdvZ-kgDEo8F4JB5PN4kLDUtkEm4CU8NPFKIRenlSaAAGQJRKYcgpArwTLZPKpdLMlzFeaLeRggBCDGQAB5kf4IQAPWHUPAAJUkHFUVGF7Iy3HMBLcROQJPghAA2gBdcm6Qg5PKhcJcYUAaUgxEgUqmVDwquZ1NAAGt7RxoL5DLheHIJLNHdKXf6Ufq7YRDTlzCVwqgA-EY9xExFLgdVBUM0mwfExdhhQAFJ706zNEXByQ5Xjymx2AAqWNFIfN6fCXdAmu18TL0PIsNU1fbGZNJdUHFIsGQkGFDds8BbEjbtbrJRchbBAGEuIg2Jx4KXy0Oq2vmHXQIvm62a5eLRmdJqM8wuMgOAc3DE0OYAERcH+vDJkovACFmzRcq+74nG+8AHuwXB4uY4HUNmtB4EwnrwBwfDwBcfIBnu8GSIhx4DhWw6jrW9bWEuK7zve5rFN2cEIUebggTgeJcdgLFdlYjb2GxpFHvxQyaCUiyECwEIzqwtr2pK4aukyaAet6hC+pG-hBiGynOoRUYxnGCbdrxqb2p2Xa9uoOqgBRZ4jheOSbv2U4znOopgieg6Vs5TG0UJDEueaIRPmAL6se+n6QN+HC-n+1ysEBoIBrw2pQd2glLiQkB8DpxaOf51GXkF9F3u28a8RldlZaAEkSWMhWnPgABWpF4FYYhWHOxy0GlSi0CcqhMOw5CaDySyFd5AZqBoBkyqAWE4XhRp4kaQZgiY2BmHipKPuEYgMPg2AglUZjbgGO17UE9TRBhpr8XB7IMGwirmMdp0ghZ+QcmgvBfWdsx9oV83IFkwSNZJOhFsR7FIRw7WdRCLAxHOfwAqhVDocwODYPgmDMJ6wFgiQFa6DQPVI5gp3EKQiqQJiPhw-uonWkW4OLRGK24fAm2FfKyBbKweRBJaCS-UWs1KODW0BkLItXrZxJg3V7nTrOjFgor2AnAAPo4HCwFQOT8b9bpoMMow6DuVgwhQhWCq6IbArMPyY0iYJ4FQMAIHCtCfA4TMvSc+BCniiAFUWzsy-48ZQc1ABi-uaOHyBuGcf6RNEHCpdJsnmAA+jV5PkCaAAGAASUQxKAAAkwRJEMFeJ7DGxbDQaCwMHfxYhCqhTi0BCSJgQrYnwvz1OQMy0M8RxvJT-QzyCOV2I4zhz0gjohrCVBp0KmfwP+mBlPnyAybMxel0kjL-ZXcgd9s8AAORhxQzDMJAYh7w3TcVi3NuYBH6bG2PwRUnoD4ZyzqfKg59L4JBLmCWqaBajL26Cgjo6DIKsgSFDR6k5NZeWnt0HILggH6Cfl3Hu2J+7NCHrwJoeNx6nHgNgYgXAkCWznmgF4-VZySl3nCKBbhkr-hzjEVKf4ADqipthSPWKAqgr9360E-t-Pef4KGT1UJ6LQ6dRHyRPmfXgABWMxXIgA)

Comment: Thanks for your time and the super quick answer, Mirco! This works great and your explanation is absolutely coherent. It's logical that I have to narrow down the Signal definitions object to be a Record of the intended types. Then I wasn't that far away from the right solution. ;). Unfortunately my reputation is too low for now, so my up-voting isn't visible yet... ;)